# Prolog result not multiplying

Tags: prolog

I have the following prolog program:

```
 square([H|T], X) :-
    squareCompare(T, H, X).

 squareCompare([], X, X * X ).
 squareCompare([H|T], V, Result) :-
    (V * V) < (H * H),
    squareCompare(T, V, Result);
    (V * V) > (H * H),
    squareCompare(T, H, Result).
```

When I enter:

```
square([7, 5, 2], Result).
```

I get `Result = 2 * 2`, what I want is `Result = 4`.

This program searches for the smallest square of the element in the list.

Comment: This is Prolog 101. You need `is/2` to evaluate: `X is 2*2`. Please, please _please_ consult a book or documentation!

Comment: `X*X` is not equal to `X` times `X`. Prolog is in fact a very "*thin*" language I would say (which is in my opinion a good idea). Prolog sees `X*X` as `*(X,X)` so a functor with two arguments.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so would I do squareCompare([], X, *(X,X) ).  Also  I have saw this http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=*/2  but I need an example. Could you show me an example.

Comment: @DanielLyons squareCompare([], X, X is */2 ). The website swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?function=*/2  is not very clear in how to use it.

Comment: @Nameishi: no you should call the predicate `is/2`, so `squareCompare([], X, Y) :- Y is X*X.` or `squareCompare([], X, Y) :- is(Y,X*X).`.

Comment: Your suggestion of using `*(X,X)` still won't work. In Prolog, that's just a term which is in fact equivalent to the syntax `X*X`. If you want to evaluate a term as an arithmetic expression, you must use`is/2` or CLP(FD). Prolog doesn't assume your term is to be evaluated. That's part of the power of Prolog. It allows you to easily reason about expressions without evaluation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem squareCompare([], X, Y) :- Y is X*X.  Is the answer..thank you.

Comment: When using a term as an argument, it's just a term. So to Prolog, `squareCompare([], X, X is */2)` is actually invalid syntax. `X is */2` isn't valid in any context. You need to include it as a separate statement in your implementation as @WillemVanOnsem has indicated in his comments. Note also that arithmetic comparison operators such as `>/2` also evaluate expressions, so your statements like `(V * V) < (H * H)` do indeed work since the `*` will be evaluated in this context. But no matter how hard you try, Prolog will NOT evaluate expressions inline in the arguments. It's not C/C++, etc.

Comment: @lurker so is that the same with passing a list also? is that why you have to pass either an empty list [ ] or send a list like [H | T]?  and I get errors when I tried to pass and entire list .

Comment: You should be able to pass any valid prolog term, including an "entire list". Prolog just does not perform "evaluation" in line of any terms that represent some kind of expression. If you get an error passing a list, that's a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the lack of arithmetic evaluation (is/2) as pointed out in the comments there's also an issue with using `<`/2 and `>`/2: your predicate doesn't work for list with consecutive repetitions, e.g.:

```
?- square([7,7],X).
false.
```

where the expected result would be 49. You can remedy that by replacing `<`/2 by `=<`/2 or `>`/2 by `>=`/2 in your recursive rule of squareCompare/3:

```
squareCompare([], X, Y) :-
   Y is X*X.
squareCompare([H|T], V, Result) :-
  (V * V) < (H * H),
  squareCompare(T, V, Result);
  (V * V) >= (H * H),
  squareCompare(T, H, Result).
```

Now the predicate yields the desired result:

```
?- square([7,7],X).
X = 49.
```

Following another suggestion in the comments, you could opt to use CLP(FD) to make the predicate work both ways. In that case the predicate resembles a true relation so it'd be appropriate to give it a more descriptive name that reflects this fact, say list_minsquare/2. And since you are interested in the smallest square, why not pass around the squares as arguments rather than the numbers? Worst case: the root of the smallest square is the last list element, then there's no difference. Best case: the root of the smallest square is the first list element, then you only calculate it once instead of length-of-list times. Putting all this together:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_minsquare([H|T],X) :-
   S #= H*H, 
   list_square_minsquare(T,S,X).

list_square_minsquare([],S,S).
list_square_minsquare([H|T],S,Result) :-
   S #< (H*H),
   list_square_minsquare(T,S,Result).
list_square_minsquare([H|T],S,Result) :-
   H2 #= (H*H),
   S #>= H2,
   list_square_minsquare(T,H2,Result).
```

Now let's see some action. Your example query yields the desired result:

```
?- list_minsquare([7,4,2],X).
X = 4.
```

Consecutive repetitions also don't cause troubles:

```
?- list_minsquare([7,7],X).
X = 49.
```

Partially instantiated lists lead to all possible solutions being produced:

```
?- list_minsquare([7,Y,2],X).
X = 4,                        % <- 1st answer: X=4 if
Y^2#=_G670,
_G670 in 50..sup ;            % Y^2 is between 50 and sup
Y in -1..1,                   % <- 2nd answer: if Y in -1..1
Y^2#=X,                       % then X=Y^2
X in 0..1 ;
X = 4,                        % <- 3rd answer: X=4
Y in -7.. -1\/1..7,           % if Y in -7..-1 or 1..7 
Y^2#=_G1754,
_G1754 in 4..49.              % and Y^2 in 4..49
```

In the above example there are three possibilities for `Y` none of which has a unique solution, hence you get residual goals in the answers. If you wish to get concrete solutions you can constrain the range of `Y` and ask for concrete numbers with label/1:

```
?- Y in 0..3, list_minsquare([7,Y,2],X), label([Y]).
Y = X, X = 0 ;
Y = X, X = 1 ;
Y = 2,
X = 4 ;
Y = 3,
X = 4.
```

The most general query works as well. However, it is listing the solutions in an unfair manner:

```
?- list_minsquare(L,X).
L = [_G97],                      % <- 1st solution
_G97^2#=X,
X in 0..sup ;
L = [_G266, _G269],              % <- 2nd solution
_G266^2#=X,
X in 0..sup,
X+1#=_G309,
_G309 in 1..sup,
_G332#>=_G309,
_G332 in 1..sup,
_G269^2#=_G332 ;
L = [_G494, _G497, _G500],       % <- 3rd solution
_G494^2#=X,
X in 0..sup,
X+1#=_G540,
X+1#=_G552,
_G540 in 1..sup, 
_G575#>=_G540,
_G575 in 1..sup,
_G500^2#=_G575,
_G552 in 1..sup,
_G620#>=_G552,
_G620 in 1..sup,
_G497^2#=_G620 ;
.
.
.
```

You only get one solution for every list length before moving on to the next length. You can get a fair ordering by prefixing a goal length/2 in the query. Then you'll get all possibilities for every list length before moving on:

```
?- length(L,_), list_minsquare(L,X).
L = [_G339],                    % <- 1st solution: list with one element
_G339^2#=X,
X in 0..sup ;
L = [_G1036, _G1039],           % <- 2nd solution: list with two elements
_G1036^2#=X,                    % X is square of 1st element
X in 0..sup,
X+1#=_G1079,
_G1079 in 1..sup,
_G1102#>=_G1079,
_G1102 in 1..sup,
_G1039^2#=_G1102 ;
L = [_G935, _G938],             % <- 3rd solution: list with two elements
_G935^2#=_G954,
_G954 in 0..sup,
_G954#>=X,
X in 0..sup,
_G938^2#=X ;                    % X is square of 2nd element
.
.
.
```

Of course you can also constrain and label the numbers in the list for the above query and you'll get concrete numbers in the still infinitely many solutions (since there are infinitely many list lengths).

```
?- length(L,_), L ins 1..2, list_minsquare(L,X), label(L).
L = [1],
X = 1 ;
L = [2],
X = 4 ;
L = [1, 2],
X = 1 ;
L = [1, 1],
X = 1 ;
L = [2, 1],
X = 1 ;
L = [2, 2],
X = 4 ;
L = [1, 2, 2],
X = 1 ;
L = [1, 2, 1],
X = 1 ;
L = [1, 1, 2],
X = 1 ;
L = [2, 1, 2],
X = 1 ;
.
.
.
```